# Omegahat SSOAP error - trying to get slot "name" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots

Tags: r, soap

I am trying to use the script below (source: Alexandre Rademaker) to process a vendor WSDL using SSOAP package, however hit the hard error below and not able to proceed further.  In verbose mode I see that the processWSDL function was able to process couple of items before it hit this error.   Did any one has any success in working around this SSOAP error? Appreciate your response.

```
library(SSOAP)
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

wsdl = getURL("https://<URL>/wsdl")
doc  <- xmlInternalTreeParse(wsdl) ## I see the formatted XML 
def <- processWSDL(doc, verbose = TRUE)  ##  ERROR below 

Error in FUN(X[[6L]], ...) : 
  trying to get slot "name" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In processAttribute(type, name, namespaceDefs = namespaceDefs, targetNamespace = targetNamespace,  :
  <fixme> Skipping children in <attribute> definition
2: In processAttribute(type, name, namespaceDefs = namespaceDefs, targetNamespace = targetNamespace,  :
  <fixme> Skipping children in <attribute> definition
3: In processAttribute(type, name, namespaceDefs = namespaceDefs, targetNamespace = targetNamespace,  :
  <fixme> Skipping children in <attribute> definition
4: In processAttribute(type, name, namespaceDefs = namespaceDefs, targetNamespace = targetNamespace,  :
  <fixme> Skipping children in <attribute> definition
5: In processAttribute(type, name, namespaceDefs = namespaceDefs, targetNamespace = targetNamespace,  :
  <fixme> Skipping children in <attribute> definition
```